# Overwrite Magento Core Account Controller (modifying login Action & login post action) - new Module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, customer, custom

I have been trying without success to overwrite a couple of functions in the Account Controller within the customer folder of Magento core (originally I had just modified the core files, but soon realised that isn't the correct way).

To get to where I am currently I have:

1. Created a folder structure in `app/code/local`:
   My folder structure is:

   ```
   - Speedcrete (module name)
       - Customer (core magento module to overwrite)
           - controllers (contains accountcontroller.php)
           - etc (which contains the modules config.xml)
   ```
2. Created an XML file called `Speedcrete_All.xml` in `app/etc/modules`

   The files look like:
   Account controller:

   ```
   <?php
   /**
    * Customer account controller
    *
    * @category   Speedcrete
    * @package    Speedcrete_Customer
    * @author     Speedcrete 
    */
   require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
   //we need to add this one since Magento wont recognize it automatically

   class Speedcrete_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController 
   {
       public function indexAction()
       {
           echo "jlkgfjdlfjgf";
           die();
           parent::indexAction();
       }

       /**
        * Customer login form page
        */
       public function loginAction()
       {
           echo "hello world i am being overwritten";
           die();
           // if we've got come from the checkout page, send variable to front end to be displayed as message
           if (isset($_GET['checkout_page'])) {
               $origin_page = $_GET['checkout_page'];
               $coupon_code = $_GET['coupon_code'];

               Mage::register('message' , 'You need to be logged in before you can use coupons!');
               Mage::register('checkout_flag', '1');
               Mage::register('coupon_code', $coupon_code);

           }
           if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
               $this->_redirect('*/*/');
               return;
           }
           $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Login-Required', 'true');
           $this->loadLayout();
           $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
           $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
           $this->renderLayout();
       }

       /**
        * Login post action
        */
       public function loginPostAction()
       {
           echo "hkjhfkjhdskfhkjdfsh";
           die();
           if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
               $this->_redirect('*/*/');
               return;
           }

           if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
               $this->_redirect('*/*/');
               return;
           }
           $session = $this->_getSession();

           if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
               $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
               //hidden field in front end
               if($login['checkout_flag'] == 1) {
                   $checkout_flag = $login['checkout_flag'];
                   $coupon_code = $login['coupon_code'];
               } else {
                   $checkout_flag = '';
                   $coupon_code = '';
               }

               if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                   try {
                       $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                       if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
                           $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
                       }
                   } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                       switch ($e->getCode()) {
                           case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                               $value = $this->_getHelper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                               $message = $this->_getHelper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value);
                               break;
                           case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                               $message = $e->getMessage();
                               break;
                           default:
                               $message = $e->getMessage();
                       }
                       $session->addError($message);
                       $session->setUsername($login['username']);
                   } catch (Exception $e) {
                       // Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
                   }
               } else {
                   $session->addError($this->__('Login and password are required.'));
               }
           }

           $this->_loginPostRedirect($checkout_flag, $coupon_code);
       }

       /**
        * Define target URL and redirect customer after logging in
        */
       protected function _loginPostRedirect($checkout_flag, $coupon_code)
       {
           $session = $this->_getSession();
           //var_dump($checkout_flag);
           //die();
           if ($checkout_flag == "") {

               if (!$session->getBeforeAuthUrl() || $session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::getBaseUrl()) {
                   // Set default URL to redirect customer to
                   $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->_getHelper('customer')->getAccountUrl());
                   // Redirect customer to the last page visited after logging in
                   if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
                       if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(
                           Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_STARTUP_REDIRECT_TO_DASHBOARD
                       )) {

                           $referer = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME);
                           if ($referer) {
                               // Rebuild referer URL to handle the case when SID was changed
                               $referer = $this->_getModel('core/url')
                                   ->getRebuiltUrl( $this->_getHelper('core')->urlDecodeAndEscape($referer));
                               if ($this->_isUrlInternal($referer)) {
                                   $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($referer);
                               }
                           }
                       } else if ($session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {

                           $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
                       }
                   } else {
                       $session->setBeforeAuthUrl( $this->_getHelper('customer')->getLoginUrl());
                   }
               } else if ($session->getBeforeAuthUrl() ==  $this->_getHelper('customer')->getLogoutUrl()) {

                   $session->setBeforeAuthUrl( $this->_getHelper('customer')->getDashboardUrl());
               } else {

                   if (!$session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
                       $session->setAfterAuthUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl());
                   }
                   if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
                       $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
                   }
               }
               $this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));
           } else {

               $this->_redirect('checkout/cart', array('_query' => 'checkout_page=1&coupon_code='.$coupon_code));
           }
       }


   }
   ```
3. `config.xml` within module folder

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Speedcrete_Customer>
               <version>1.0</version>
           </Speedcrete_Customer>
       </modules>

       <frontend>
           <routers>
               <customer>
                   <args>
                       <modules>
                           <Speedcrete_Customer_controllers_Account before="Mage_Customer">Speedcrete_Customer_controllers_Account</Speedcrete_Customer_controllers_Account>
                       </modules>
                   </args>
               </customer>
           </routers>
       </frontend>
       <layout>
           <updates>
               <mage_customer>
                   <file>speedcrete.xml</file>
               </mage_customer>
           </updates>
       </layout>
   </config>
   ```
4. then finally the `Speedcrete_All.xml` which is within `app/etc/modules`

   ```
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Speedcrete_Customer>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>local</codePool>
               <depends>
                   <Mage_Customer />
               </depends>
           </Speedcrete_Customer>
       </modules>
   </config>
   ```

Hopefully this makes sense, nothing happens when refreshing the account login page either when logging in!

Comment: just need to change Speedcrete_Customer_controllers_Account to Speedcrete_Customer in your config.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your module is registered. `

> system->configuration->advance->disable modules output

Then in your config.xml file change the code like

```
  <frontend>
    <routers>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Speedcrete_Customer before="Mage_Customer">Speedcrete_Customer</Speedcrete_Customer>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

In `config.xml` this

```
    <routers>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Speedcrete_Customer_controllers_Account before="Mage_Customer">Speedcrete_Customer_controllers_Account</Speedcrete_Customer_controllers_Account>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
```

Should be

```
    <routers>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Speedcrete_Customer before="Mage_Customer">Speedcrete_Customer</Speedcrete_Customer>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
```